# How to add listeners to bidirectionally bound objects

Tags: java, javafx, garbage-collection

I am trying to bind a TextArea's textProperty to a StringProperty in controller's initialize() method.

Both of them are listened by listeners to perform some behavior when value changes.

But something weird happens.

I build a simple model to reproduce the situation.

Main.java

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 400, 300));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

sample.fxml

```
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.TextArea?>
<GridPane fx:controller="sample.Controller"
          xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" alignment="center" hgap="10" vgap="10"
          prefHeight="300" prefWidth="400">
  <TextArea fx:id="textArea"/>
</GridPane>
```

I don't think the above code is relevant to this question. But just in case, I put it here.

Here is the Controller.

Controller.java

```
package sample;

import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;

public class Controller {

  @FXML
  TextArea textArea;

  private StringProperty toBind = new SimpleStringProperty();

  public void initialize() {
    textArea.textProperty().bindBidirectional(toBind);

    textArea.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
      System.out.print("textArea: ");
      System.out.println(newValue);
    });

    toBind.addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
      System.out.print("toBind: ");
      System.out.println(newValue);
    });
  }
}
```

With this controller, when I input the sequence 'abcd' to the textarea, I get:

```
textArea: a
textArea: ab
textArea: abc
textArea: abcd
```

It seems that the change event for the toBind object is not fired.

So then I tried to print the value of toBind in textArea's Listener.

The new code is:

```
package sample;

import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;

public class Controller {

  @FXML
  TextArea textArea;

  private StringProperty toBind = new SimpleStringProperty();

  public void initialize() {
    textArea.textProperty().bindBidirectional(toBind);

    textArea.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
      System.out.print("textArea: ");
      System.out.println(newValue);

      // ----- New statements. -----
      System.out.print("toBind value in textArea: ");
      System.out.println(toBind.get());
      // ----- New statements. -----
    });

    toBind.addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
      System.out.print("toBind: ");
      System.out.println(newValue);
    });
  }
}
```

Then I got:

```
toBind: a
textArea: a
toBind value in textArea: a
toBind: ab
textArea: ab
toBind value in textArea: ab
toBind: abc
textArea: abc
toBind value in textArea: abc
toBind: abcd
textArea: abcd
toBind value in textArea: abcd
```

Why does this happen? The event is fired properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your binding, and the `toBind` property, are getting garbage collected.

A succinct description of the "premature garbage collection" problem is provided by Tomas Mikula on his [blog](http://tomasmikula.github.io/blog/2015/02/10/the-trouble-with-weak-listeners.html).

---

First, a quick aside for anyone trying to reproduce this issue. Since the behavior described depends on garbage collection occurring, it may not always occur (it depends on memory allocation, the GC implementation being used, and other factors). If you add the line

```
root.setOnMouseClicked(e -> System.gc());
```

to the `start()` method, then clicking on the blank area in the scene will request garbage collection, and the issue will (at least be more likely to) manifest itself after that (if it hasn't already).

---

The problem is that bindings use `WeakListener`s to listen to changes in properties and propagate those changes to the bound properties. A weak listener is designed not to prevent the property to which it is attached from being garbage collected if there are no other live references to that property. (The rationale is to avoid having to force programmers to manually clean up bindings when properties are no longer in scope.)

In your example code, the controller and its property `toBind` are eligible for garbage collection.

After the `start()` method completes, all that you are guaranteed to have references to are the `Application` instance created when you call `launch()`, the `Stage` that is shown, and anything referenced from those. This of course includes the `Scene` (referenced by the `Stage`), its `root`, the children of the `root`, their children, etc, properties of those, and (non-weak) listeners on any of those properties.

So the `stage` has a reference to the `scene`, which has a reference to the `GridPane` which is its root, and that has a reference to the `TextArea`.

The `TextArea` has a reference to the listener that is attached to it, but that listener keeps no additional references.

(In the second version of your code, the non-weak `ChangeListener` attached to the `textArea.textProperty()` has a reference to `toBind`. So in that version, the `ChangeListener` prevents `toBind` from being GC'd, and you see the output from the listener on it.)

When you load the FXML, the `FXMLLoader` creates the controller instance. While that controller instance has references to the string property and the text area, the reverse is not true. So once loading is complete, there are no live references to the controller, and it is eligible for garbage collection, along with the `StringProperty` it defines. The text area's `textProperty()` has only a *weak reference* to a listener on `toBind`, so the text area cannot prevent `toBind` being garbage collected.

In most real scenarios, this won't be a problem. You are unlikely to create this additional `StringProperty` unless you are going to use it somewhere. So if you add in any code that uses this in a "natural" way, you are likely to see the issue disappear.

So, e.g., suppose you add a label:

```xml
<Label fx:id="label" GridPane.rowIndex="1"/>
```

and bind its text to the property:

```
  public void initialize() {
    textArea.textProperty().bindBidirectional(toBind);

    textArea.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
      System.out.print("textArea: ");
      System.out.println(newValue);
    });

    toBind.addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
      System.out.print("toBind: ");
      System.out.println(newValue);
    });

    label.textProperty().bind(toBind);
  }
```

Then the scene has a reference to the label, etc, so it is not GC'd, and the label's `textProperty` has a weak reference via its binding to `toBind`. Since the `label` is not GC'd, the weak reference survives garbage collection, and `toBind` cannot be GC'd, so you see the output you expect.

Alternatively, if you reference the `toBind` property elsewhere, e.g. in the `Application` instance:

```
public class Controller {

  @FXML
  TextArea textArea;

  private StringProperty toBind = new SimpleStringProperty();

  public void initialize() {
    textArea.textProperty().bindBidirectional(toBind);

    textArea.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
      System.out.print("textArea: ");
      System.out.println(newValue);
    });

    toBind.addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
      System.out.print("toBind: ");
      System.out.println(newValue);
    });

  }

  public StringProperty boundProperty() {
      return toBind ;
  }
}
```

and then

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    private StringProperty boundProperty ;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        Parent root = loader.load();
        Controller controller = loader.getController();
        boundProperty = controller.boundProperty();
        root.setOnMouseClicked(e -> System.gc());
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 400, 300));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

you again see the expected behavior (even after garbage collection).

Finally (and this last point gets very subtle), if you replace the listener on `textArea.textProperty()` with an anonymous inner class:

```
textArea.textProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {

  @Override
  public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue, String newValue) {
    System.out.print("textArea: ");
    System.out.println(newValue);
  }
});
```

then this also prevents GC of `toBind`. The reason here is that instances of anonymous inner classes contain implicit references to the enclosing instance (i.e. the instance of the controller in this case): and here the controller keeps a reference to `toBind`. Lambda expressions, by contrast, don't do this.

Comment: wow ... what an excellent answer! Have been bitten by weak listeners occasionally, but didn't see this

Answer (score 1):

I found 2 solutions to you answer

**1:**

Declare the StringProperty as `static`

**OR 2:**

In the TextArea Listener just call `toBind.get()`

*But honestly I don't know why those work.*

Comment: See my answer. Both of these, while kind of unnatural things to do, prevent `toBind` being garbage collected. The first is obvious (the reference moves to class scope); the second because the (non-weak) listener on the text area's `textProperty` (which is necessarily referenced by the text property, and hence reachable from the stage reference) contains a reference to `toBind`).